# Strategy for using custom css properties to debug LESS css mixins

Tags: google-chrome, less

I have created a couple LESS mixins to help me during debugging.

```
.comment(@name, @comment)
{
    & when (@debugMode = true)
    {
        -rr-@{name}: @comment;
    }
}
```

then I call it in a breakpoint (I have mixins that I call for each breakpoint width).

```
 .comment(video-layout, ontop);
```

This outputs a 'comment' in my CSS.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 23em) {

    #pnlBladeVideos 
    {
       -rr-video-layout: ontop;
    }
}
```

The idea being that when creating a responsive design with breakpoints I can find properties I may have used in mixins to create my css. (yes I know about sourcemap support but this is above and beyond that).

Unfortunately because `-rr-video-layout` is not recognized by the browser it just crosses it out. Sure I can still see the value, which is useful but I'd really like to see which one is actually in effect for a particular breakpoint.

[image]

Is there any way to either :

- Make Chrome recognize an arbitrary css property prefix or name
- Use some css property that is inert and has no effect
- Make a Chrome extension to recognize - but effectively ignore a custom css property
- Do something else smart to get the same effect?

Answer (score 4):

`content` probably can do the trick (since it affects only `::before` and `::after` but still considered as valid property for any selector (at least by Chrome)). I.e.:

```
.comment(@name, @comment) when (@debugMode = true) {
    content: "@{name}: @{comment}";
}
```

Comment: this is kind of useful, but 'content' will make images disappear :-)

Comment: also for the overriding to work I'd have to make one single 'content' property for all properties in a breakpoint because I wouldn't have the granularity of being able to override the css corresponding to individual parameters if they all had the same name